# Is Borland C++ v3 for DOS available anywhere now?

Tags: c++, dos, turbo-c++

I'm looking for a copy of either Borland C++ v3 or Turbo C++ which can run on DOS, but my searches are turning up a blank. I vaguely remember a free Turbo version available, but can't track it down.

Are there free/pay versions of these still available? Is http://www.embarcadero.com my best hope?

Thanks for any info...

Answer (score 4):

Look here for the first version of TC++: http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum

Comment: This museum version of Turbo C++ is available free of charge to registered users of C++Builder 2007 or later, RAD Studio 2007 or later or Embarcadero All-Access. Registered users of those products can click through to the Turbo C++ version 1.01 download page to download the software (2.7mb). :-(
I remember this used to be available to anyone but no more...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only legally available free tools for people without a recent C++Builder license is the 5.5 command line compiler available [here](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/item/24778)

Answer (score 0):

You can only get it from http://www.emsps.com/ they sell old software.

Answer (score 0):

Turbo C/C++ 3 appear frequently on eBay.